# How do I actually use the files generated from Terraformer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I don't have much experience with Terraform or cloud infrastructure in general, but I need to clone an existing production GCP project so I can at least get a basic staging backend set up. I figured Terraformer would be great for the first part, i.e. generating .tf files from the project, and after some configuration, I got it to create a whole bunch of files. The question is, how can I actually use them? They're all in a bunch of different subdirectories and I don't exactly know how to get `terraform init` and `plan` to read all of that. I'm happy to give more details, if needed. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: start simple once you get the concept then complicate it as much as you like... I think the output of Terraformer on your existing production project is overwhelming you, not the best introduction to Terraform... but in a nutshell you run terraform init and plan on the same folder that contains the .TF files

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but I've started on a new project and am currently being tasked with creating a staging backend with very high priority, and I honestly wouldn't be able to do it from scratch without having a week or two to just look at all the code since I'm not really familiar with the codebase/infrastructure.
Either way, I did try that, but I don't think Terraform is able to go inside the subfolders and do anything with them. It just says there are no changes to be made.

Comment: If it says there are no changes to be made is because TF is pointing to the production project, you now need to change it to staging... but how was production environment created? that was all manually?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the folder structure you are looking at?

Comment: Suggestion. There are no shortcuts. You must spend the time to learn both Terraform and Google Cloud. You mention you don't have two weeks. Think again - you will spend months learning just Terraform and how it manages cloud resources.

Comment: Also, note that Terraform cannot reproduce every resource in Google Cloud. Terraformer is a tool to help you. Don't count on it to reliably replicate your environment.

Comment: I did change any references to the prod project to the staging project, so I'm not really sure. I think it's just straight up ignoring that directory. [Here is a picture of how the folder structure generally is](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/766759008664027146/1187887216123457596/image.png?ex=6598852e&is=6586102e&hm=5505491128b0783291c2e01e98b082c14526e3fcfebc3a9e3b909361ef8432f9&)

There's also my variables.tf file and versions.tf in the root directory.

Comment: @JohnHanley Again, I totally agree with you, but unfortunately it's not an option here since the execs want a staging environment asap. I am also aware that it won't replicate it 100%, but I just want some sort of skeleton to work off of that is similar to what we already have.

Comment: I added that image to the question... those folders I suspect are terraform modules, can you show more of the structure, there must be more at the "top folder" (fine-booking) that ties all those

Comment: Reading more in the documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer?tab=readme-ov-file#resource-structure

looks like those folders are NOT terraform modules doc shows: `Terraformer by default separates each resource into a file, which is put into a given service directory.` so you might have to jump inside each and do a terraform apply or transform all that to modules and have one main file that calls them all

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yes, they do look like modules but they aren't. I did try using `path-pattern` once before but I wasn't sure about the syntax. I'll try it again and see if I can flatten it that way.

Comment: Yes, that worked to make it all one file. However, there are a bunch of conflicts and errors when I try running `plan`